# -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio gives a CSS validation error

Tags: css, media-queries

I have following CSS definition:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 2dppx), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    .iconAnnotationGuideH {
        background-position: -456px -24px;
        background-size: auto 96px;
    }
}
```

When I submit it to http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to validate, it will give me some errors.

> Feature -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio doesn't exist for media null ),
>   (min-resolution: 2dppx), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
>   .iconAnnotationGuideH { background-position: -456px -24px;
>   background-size: auto 96px; } }"

What should I do?

Comment: Cause it's specific to a browser rendering engine. If you removed "-webket-" it would validate. Any reason why you're using a specific browser selector?

Comment: @Papa - `min-resolution` is the standard, not `min-device-pixel-ratio`, so even un-prefixed it will not validate :) and I don't believe it was ever implemented  without the `-moz` or `-webkit` prefixes. It's only used for legacy browser support (and Safari)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What should I do?

Absolutely nothing! The `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` is not standard and will not validate. **This is OK!** Use the validator as a guide only.

`-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` will only be used by older, webkit based browsers. If you are not worried about old browsers then you can remove it, though it seems that Safari needs it. [See browser support for `min-resolution` here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution). Look out for:

> 2 - Supported using the non-standard min/max-device-pixel-ratio

---

### So it's ok to use this?

Yes, for legacy browsers and Safari.

[From the MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio)

> -moz-device-pixel-ratio may be used for compatibility with Firefox older than 16 and **-webkit-device-pixel-ratio with WebKit-based
>   browsers that do not support dppx.**
>
> **Note:** This media feature is also implemented by Webkit as
>   -webkit-device-pixel-ratio. The min and max prefixes as implemented by Gecko are named min--moz-device-pixel-ratio and
>   max--moz-device-pixel-ratio; but the same prefixes as implemented by
>   Webkit are named -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio and
>   -webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio.

---

### Tell me a story!

[Here is the story from the w3c blog:](http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/)

> Once upon a time, Webkit decided a media query for the screen
>   resolution was needed. But rather than using the already-standardized
>   resolution media query, they invented `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`. The
>   resolution media query can take “dots per inch” and “dots per
>   centimeter”, while `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` takes “dots per px”. But
>   these are all fundamentally the same thing because 1in = 96px =
>   2.54cm. (Granted, not all of this was well-understood in 2006, so we can forgive Webkit for making something up.)

They all lived happily ever after.

The End